# cant load instagram login page with phantomjs

Tags: javascript, electron, phantomjs

i just learn about phantomjs but icant go to instagram page like example in the phantomjs.org
can somebody hepl me

i hope i can learn or get some experience form here

version windows 10
phantomjs 2.1.1
shouladi use some webdriver??,cause i read in the net so many discussed abot selenium or other webdriver

Any suggestion?

```
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = {width: 1280, height: 1024};

var testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false;

// page.settings.userAgent =  "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-G975U) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.93 Mobile Safari/537.36";
// page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebkit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.04147.105 Safari/537.36";
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  loadInProgress = true;
  console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  loadInProgress = false;
  console.log("load finished");
};

function load()
{
    page.open("https://instagram.com/accounts/login/",function(status){
      if(status==="succes"){
        page.render('1coba.jpeg',{format:'jpeg', quality:'100'});
        page.evaluate(function(){
          document.getElementsByClassName("._2hvTZ").value="username%password";
          document.getElementsByClassName(".Igw0E").submit();

        });
        
      }else{
        page.render('1coba.jpeg',{format:'jpeg', quality:'100'});
        page.evaluate(function(){
          document.getElementsByClassName("._2hvTZ").value="username&password";
          document.getElementsByClassName(".Igw0E").submit();

        });
      }
      
    })  
}
function upload()
{
    page.uploadFile('.q02Nz', '//path');    
    page.render("2coba.jpeg")
}

function finish()
{
  page.render('3coba.jpeg',{format:'jpeg',quality:'100'});
}

var steps = [
    load,
    upload,
    finish
]

interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
    console.log("step " + (testindex + 1));
    steps[testindex]();
    testindex++;
  }
  if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
    console.log("test complete!");
    phantom.exit();
  }
}, 2000);
```